# Using OWIN to validate STEAM user login without identity

Tags: c#, steam

I have been browsing endlessly without really finding the answer i am looking for.

It may even be a stupid question answered in some others form, then please direct me there.

Basically, what i need is a button that redirects to Steams logon page where the user can login with his Steam user. When he successfully does, I just need the returned SteamId, and thats bacsically it! I dont need Steam as a login service, but more as a verfication method that the provided Steam user is who he says he is - i have my own login system for user etc, which is irrelevant.

I have tried using Owin's part that has steam as OpenID provider, but for the love of me i cant figure out how to untangle it to the simple thing i need.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, according to the Steam Web API (https://steamcommunity.com/dev), Steam OpenID should do exactly what you want: `The returned Claimed ID will contain the user's 64-bit SteamID.`. Did you do all they ask for (create an API Key, etc)?

Comment: I have an API key ready, no problem. The problem is using OWINS OpenId provider to get the data without entangling with ASP.NETs Identity